# Calculate pi to the nth term with leibiniz sequence

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey I have to create a method where I have to calculate pi to a passed term (a) using the leibiniz sequence. This is what I have so far

```
public static double calculatePi(int a){
    double oddNum=1;
    double pi=0;
    for(int x=0; x<a; x++){
        if(x%2==0)
            pi=pi+(4/oddNum);
        else
                pi=pi-(4/oddNum);
        oddNum=oddNum+2;
    }
return pi;
}
```

I also need help writing a method that accepts a passed string and a (x)term. In the method it will add a "#" every x letters. So if its passed (sundae, 2) it will return su#nd#ae#. I have most of it down but theres a logical error that doesnt allow something like (cats, 3) to compile.

```
public static String addPounds(String s, int x){
    String a="";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i=i+x){
        a=(a+s.substring(i,i+x)+"#");
    }
    return a;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pi method is working fine.

You should change the other one to this. I have written it a little bit different so you get the logic easily.

```
public static String addPounds(String s, int x){
    String a = "";

    //starting from 1 so i can do mod division easily
    for(int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++){

        //check if next # has to be placed at the end
        if(i + 1 > s.length() && (i + 1) % x == 0){
            a += "#";

        //check if next # has to be placed somewhere inside the string
        }else if(i % x == 0){
            a += s.charAt(i - 1);
            a += "#";

        //oherwise just add the char at i-1
        }else {
            a += s.charAt(i - 1 );

        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your addPounds method throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with your given example (cats,3).

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i=i+x){
    a=(a+s.substring(i,i+x)+"#");
}
```

In the first execution of this for-loop, your variable 'a' will correctly be "Cat#". But now it goes wrong.
The variable 'i' gets increased to 3. And now you want to get a substring starting from the index 3 and ending with the index 6. The String "Cats" is only 4 letters, therefore the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I guess the easiest way to solve your problem would be inserting a if else statement like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i=i+x){
        if(s.length()>=i+x){
            a=(a+s.substring(i,i+x)+"#");
        }
        else{
            a= a+s.substring(i);
        }
    }
```